# Making mouse pointer invisible (x-pointer-invisible)

Tags: mouse-pointer

I am trying to hide the mouse pointer via:

```
(setq x-pointer-shape x-pointer-invisible)
(setq x-sensitive-text-pointer-shape x-pointer-invisible)
(setq void-text-area-pointer 'text)
(set-mouse-color (cdr (assoc 'mouse-color (frame-parameters))))
```

The last command is supposed to make the previous changes effective (it works with other pointer shapes), but in the case of `x-pointer-invisible` I get the error `can't set cursor shape: BadValue`.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or another way to make the mouse pointer invisible? I am looking for temporary invisibility that can be toggled on the fly.

Comment: The error is produces by `x_set_mouse_color` in `src/xfns.c:1282` and is an error that is returned by the X server after the function `XCreateFontCursor` is called, so outside of emacs control. I suspect that you either are doing it wrong or you cannot use this method at all, but that's all I can say: I don't know how to do it right or whether another method exists. Some searching uncovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11) but AFAICT the situation is far from satisfactory.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: A guess is that `x-pointer-invisible` isn't supported on your platform (or perhaps by Emacs?).

Comment: Thanks, @NickD and @Drew. For context, I have tried several ```x-pointer-*``` shapes and only ```x-pointer-invisible``` gives problems. I am on Linux/X11.

Comment: Maybe google to see if `x-pointer-invisible` is supported on GNU Linux/X11?

Comment: In the past, I used [disable-mouse](https://github.com/purcell/disable-mouse), which worked pretty well, maybe you can trigger some event on the mouse movement to disable/enable this minor mode.

Good luck!

Comment: @f-sasa, thank you for the suggestion. I have tried it out and ```disable-mouse``` does not work for me (Emacs 26.3 on Linux).